# Check ocx is registered or not

Tags: c#

how to check ocx is registered or not.i want to check in particular mswinsck.ocx,richtx32.ocx are registered

Comment: [OleView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693754(VS.85).aspx) should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the object's CLSID? then check the registry if the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{...}` exists

Answer (score 1):

You can search your ocx's name in the regedit